# How can I use DirectInput to create a chat box in my game?

Tags: directx, directinput

The only solution I can think of is to check which character is being pressed and then display that character on the screen. However, this strikes me as really tiresome and a generally poor solution. I can't think of another solution though. I thought about using the windows message loop instead of DirectInput, but I would still have to check on a character-by-character basis (unless I am misunderstanding something), so it seems like I would have the same problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a few classes to assist you with this:

- A "TextBuffer" that stores and provides typing operations on the currently edited string (including caret position etc).
- A "TextPanel" or "TextWidget" which draws/displays a TextBuffer and recieves+forwards keypress messages when it has *focus*.

Encoding a concept of input "focus" in your UI can help simplify the control flow greatly.